# Transport package through tunnel from gateway to Server without changing source ip

Tags: networking, router, vpn, tunnel

[image of network layout, cannot embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WVH7.png)

### I have following Challenge:

I have a dynamic IP (changes nearly every day) and want to have a static one.

I need that static IP for some services and can't use dyndns or something on dns level.

### What I tried or researched so far

First I tried to forward packages from my Gateway to my Modem with iptables forwarding, but that changes the source ip of the packet to my gateway ip.

Then I tried ssh-tunneling ports to my server, but with the same effect.

Then I tried nginx, haproxy,... but that terminates my ssl connections and i have the certificates at the hoster and I'm not happy with that.

Then I found GRE, IPinIP, tincvpn, ipsec transport mode, or thought maybe I have to implement something myself, but I wanted to ask for ideas first.

### Question

How can i transport the incoming packet e.g. to port 80 at my gateway to my server, so that I see the source IP of the Client and my Server can answer that packet, so that the client gets the response? Also I want that tunnel to reconnect (or so) if my public IP at the homenetwork changes. If you need more information, i'm happy to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of encapsulation (tunneling generally), you CANNOT have the source IP on the actual packets unmodified. However, you CAN look for alternate ways to preserve the source IP/port.

You generally will NOT be able to respond directly from your dynamic address, because your local system attempting to spoof static IP should have it's attempt discarded by your upstream. The response has to traverse back to your hoster before going out again. There are solutions like IPVS Direct Routing (also called server return), but they require being on the same physical network segment as your hosters IP.

On the easiest side, would probably be IVPS TUN that puts a tunnel between the hoster and your server. How you run the tunnel is up to you, it just lets you fake the addressing somewhat. You'd have to have a dedicated IP at the hoster to do it.

On the software side with less network modifications, you don't HAVE to have SSL terminated at the hoster. You can use HAProxy in a pure TCP mode for example, with the PROXYv2 protocol conveying the original source IP data. An example configuration might run HAProxy at the hoster, in TCP mode, explicitly using SSL client certificates to securely connect to the final Server, and using the PROXYv2 protocol to convey the original IP data.

You still need a way to have HAProxy to reliably connect to the server even when it's IP changes: this could be Dynamic DNS (so HAProxy looks up the active address for the server, and never discloses it to the end-user), various configuration hacks in HAProxy for dynamic server addresses, or combining a tunneling solution at this point (the server connects OUT to the HAProxy host to establish the tunnel, and addressing inside the tunnel is used for HAProxy to connect back).

All of the above solutions WILL add latency and bugs (consider a LAN client parallel to the server, which has to go to the hoster & back multiple times).

All of the above said, you never established WHY you wanted to do this in the first place.

I would consider moving the service outside of the "Homenetwork" environment rather than trying to get the packets into it, or improve the service to support DNS (and thus open it to various dynamic DNS solutions). I do understand some situations might not work with this (like the server is really controlling some physical device located in the Homenetwork scope)

Comment: Haproxy in TCP mode is not possible, because I have services that require also udp.
I looked into ipvs and really liked it. It worked and would probably be quite stable with 2+ vdsl connections (2 providers), BUT your right and i rented a cheap server for 20 euro per month and moved the webservices that need to be publicly available and for sharing 8TB+ data and services that don't need to be accessed publicly i created a vpn network with tinc.